Is it possible to limit completions for certain tokens?
I am using lazyvim with mason + blink + lspconfig. It almost perfectly works with provided defaults, but there is one thing i don't like. I really want to disable completions on text objects, and text completions on any other object.

As you can see in this example - it tries to provide text autocompletions, even for context that is not suitable for text.
i want to disable text autocompletions completely (pun intended) in any context. I was digging lsp configuration but couldn't figure out how to do it. Also i'm not sure if it is lsp-config who is responsible for such configuration, or cmp plugin (which is blink in my situation)
Please help

By “text” do you mean inside of quotes (a “string”)? “Text object” is a specific term with specific meaning in Vim, so I want to help your question be clear so that it may receive useful answers. (Please also mention what plugin or standard feature is providing the (auto)completion.)

It appears that blink just couldn't read my config. The easiest way to solve it is to put
opts = {
  sources = {
    default = {"lsp", "path", "snippets" --exclude buffer from here!
    }
  }
}

And you're good to go!
